# Unexpected token in CSS when editing it in vnext

Tags: html, computer-science, mozilla

When I try to write some css through Vnext or Webmatrix v2 beta I got error that unxpected token : 
sometime I change something and got error that unexpected error ;

When I try this

```
body
{
    background-color :Aqua;
}
```

I wonder all browser (moz,chrome) give me error that **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"**

Later I save it from vs2010 but i still have error. Can someone tell me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The error suggests that you're trying to load your CSS as if it were Javascript.

Comment: +1 for everyone that was coding so quickly they didn't realize this.

Comment: I am coding for 3 years and I had a little wtf moment lol, too much copy paste

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Vnext is expecting the `:` to be beside the `background-color`?

Try this

`background-color: Aqua`